# How to set a bash variable in a compound xargs statement

Tags: bash, xargs

I am looking for a way to set a variable in the statements passed to xargs. The value is to be manipulated in one of the commands. Using a file or another utility is an option but I am not sure why setting the bash variable in the sequence is always coming up as empty.

```
$ ls c*txt
codebase.txt  consoleText.txt

$  ls c*txt | xargs -i bash -c "echo processing {}; v1={} && echo ${v1/txt/file}"
codebase.txt  consoleText.txt

processing codebase.txt

processing consoleText.txt
```

The example above distills the question to the basics. I was expecting the behavior to be something like this but inline:

```
$ fname=codebase.txt; echo ${fname/txt/file}
 codebase.file
```

Thank you.

Comment: Its pulling $v1 from the parent environment - you need single quotes to inhibit variable substitution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is resolving `${v1/txt/file}` to a value before the command is executed:

```
$  ls c*txt | xargs -i bash -c "echo processing {}; v1={} && echo ${v1/txt/file}"
```

And that means the bash -c doesn't even see `${v1/txt/file}`

In this line the single quotes inhibit the variable substitution so `echo processing {}; v1={} && echo ${v1/txt/file}` is actually passed to bash -c as a parameter:

```
$  ls c*txt | xargs -i bash -c 'echo processing {}; v1={} && echo ${v1/txt/file}'
```

You could accomplish the same thing by escaping the dollar sign:

```
$  ls c*txt | xargs -i bash -c "echo processing {}; v1={} && echo \${v1/txt/file}"
```